# Converse of "contains"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the simple phrase “This bottle *contains* a bee”, is there a single word that would fit the formulation of “This bee *[someword]* a bottle”?

This is for a taxonomy of edges in a graph where a node might mention another node and that mention can be classed as a particular type. For *“contains”* the mention could occur at either end of the edge (e.g. “France contains Paris”, or “Paris *[someword]* France”).

This is subtly different from equivalence establishing mentions where the edge classification means the same in both directions. For example: “France *is* Bacon” implies “Bacon *is* France” (as well as an ignorance of late 16th C history).

Some examples to work from:

- This bottle contains the bee; The bee ____ this bottle.
- Europe contains France; France _____ Europe.
- France contains Paris; Paris _____ France.
- The forest contains the temple; the temple _____ the forest.

Comment: The formulation “X [word] Y” doesn't need to be perfect grammar, just not long-winded and inverted like "X is contained by Y"

Comment: The simplest solution is "in". The bee is *in* the bottle, France is *in* Europe, Paris is *in* France, etc.

Comment: I don't think you could do better than **"is contained within"**

Comment: BTW you're asking about the converse here, not the opposite: you might want to edit your question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of "contain" would be *unloose*, *free*, *exposed*, or *exclude*, so I don't think that is what the OP had in mind.

The simplest solution is "in".

The bee is *in* the bottle, France is *in* Europe, Paris is *in* France, etc.

But if you want a fancier word, *[encapsulated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/encapsulate)*, might tick the container.  Thus,

> *the bee is encapsulated by the bottle*.

Comment: But "encapsulate" is not the converse of "contain". On the contrary, it is a **[synonym](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/encapsulate)** of "contain". From the point of view of  the OP, "the bee is encapsulated by the bottle" is no better than "the bee is contained by the bottle". They were specifically looking for  a single word that expressed the relationship of A being-inside B.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very idiomatic, but ***occupy*** fits your *bee* sample:

> **2 a** :to take up (a place or extent in space)
>
> - this chair is *occupied*
> - the fireplace will *occupy* this corner of the room
>
> **4** :to reside in as an owner or tenant
>
> - *occupies* an apartment on a two-year lease
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occupy)</sub>

However, the construction change you are trying can be considered to be a change to *passive voice*. So, the verb *contains* would change to ***is contained by*** (noted in comments to your question). A shortened form would be ***is in*** or ***is within***.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are looking for a technical word that expresses in common English the opposite **predicate** (function returning true or false) of  *contains*. The verb *occupy* might work in real life examples, but does not seem exactly applicable to your use case with a graph.

I would suggest a solution by using a little lateral thinking. We can start with an analogy: in a programming language, you would express this with a function named **is_in** or **belongs_to**.

We could "not mind manoeuvers and go straight at them", i.e. use the same device in normal English:

> This bottle contains the bee; The bee **is-in** this bottle.
>
> Europe contains France; France **is-in** Europe.
>
> France contains Paris; Paris **is-in** France.
>
> The forest contains the temple; the temple **is-in** the forest.

Non-technical people might initially frown at the hyphen, but would understand the meaning at once.

But for people in the know, it would work exactly as a transitive verb like *occupy*. Let me justify this usage by calling it **[an idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom)** (**[phrasal verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrasal%20verb)**): in principle "be in" means just "be + in". But in your mind it would be **transitive** phrasal verb (neologism) that means:

> **be-in** (transitive): in a graph, to connect a mentioned node to a mentioning node (opposite of **contain**).

(I apologize for the awkward definition and you might find a better one.)

The hyphen is optional, but it would convey this phrasal nature of your expression without ambiguity, and would be self-evident to your readers.

The justification here is expediency, shortness, and the requirement of being understood, in a technical paper. In any case, that would require a definition note in any formal paper (and needless to say, it might be considered anathema in other contexts).