# Is there a verb meaning the inverse of "to contain"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can say "My bag contains an apple", using "contain" as a transitive verb that takes the container as its subject and the thing contained as its direct object.

My question is, is there a verb such that I could describe exactly the same situation by saying "An apple VERBS my bag"? This verb, if it exists, would take the thing contained as its subject and the container as its direct object.

I can think of several multi-word phrases to express this idea, for instance, "An apple *is inside* my bag", "An apple *can be found within* my bag", or, using the passive of "contain",  "An apple *is contained by* my bag". But no single verb.

The nearest I can think of is the verb "to fill". But "An apple fills my bag" implies both that there is no other item in the bag and there is no space left in the bag. I'm looking for a verb that does not imply anything about what else the bag may or not contain or about whether any empty space is left in the bag, just that the apple is in the bag.

I feel as if there is some obvious word on the tip of my tongue, but it just won't come to me!

Comment: The apple is _in_ the bag. You need a preposition, not a verb, since neither bag nor apple are doing anything, they are just existing in a relationship that requires a preposition to express the relationship. If you reject the concept of containment, then you are left with just the concept of existence, which requires the verb _to be_.

Comment: @NigelJ, I grant you that "an apple is in my bag" expresses the idea perfectly well. I said as much when I cited "an apple is inside my bag" as being a multi-word phrase that meant the same as what I was looking for. But we *do* have the verb "to contain" despite the fact that the relationship between bag and apple involves neither of them doing anything, just existing in a relationship. It seems strange that there should be a verb to express the relationship that way round, but only a preposition for the other way round.

Comment: I'm not at all sure it _is_ strange that there's a verb to express the relationship one way and "only" a preposition for the other; these relationships aren't always neatly paired with equivalent constructions... language's architect isn't that pedantic about those sort of things. There are verbs you _can_ use but are they natural-sounding constructions? Probably not - at least, any I can think of. Whether you find an answer you're happy with or not, this question has a distinctly odd premise behind it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to avoid passive constructions entirely, but FWIW (not much, if you ask me), you might try: _An apple is held by my bag._ But _in_ is better.

Comment: @Laurel, well spotted that the question ['Converse of "contains"?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/415517/converse-of-contains) is a duplicate of my question. Unfortunately neither of the two options "That solved my problem" or "No, my question is different" exactly meets my situation. The other question is not different from mine, but it didn't solve my problem either. Of its three answers, the most upvoted one is simply wrong. Meaning no disrespect to the answerer, "encapsulate" is not the converse of contain, it is a synonym of it. The two other...

Comment: ...answers both suggest "occupy", as did @Helion in his reply to my question. As I said above this is very close to what I want, but I was planning to just wait a couple of days before accepting it to see if any other answers were offered. "Occupy" is a good answer but as NigelJ said, it does lack the concept of containment. Furthermore I've been told on other Stack Exchanges that it bad form to accept an answer immediately unless the question is such that it has an obvious single correct answer, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps ***[occupy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occupy)***?

> 2: to take up (a place or extent in space)
>   • *this chair is **occupied***
>   • *the fireplace will **occupy** this corner of the room*
>   <sub>from *[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occupy)*</sub>

Comment: Ooh, that's very close and may well be it. "An apple occupies my bag" certainly does express the idea of "subject **verbs** container"  without the unwanted extra implications of "fills".  I believe that the correct procedure for Stack Exchange questions is to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer, to see if anyone else wants to suggest something. So I won't accept it just yet. But I think you probably have answered my question - and only eleven minutes after I asked it, despite it having bugged me for *days*!

Comment: But a cow can _occupy_ a field or a mayfly can _occupy_ a few millimetres of atmosphere. The concept of containment is lost completely and even the concept of 'within-ness' is lost with _occupy_ (I would say). Containment is an active concept and being contained is a passive concept, intrinsically.

Comment: I think a field can contain one or more cows, just as the atmosphere may contain many bugs.  Seems to me containment can be passive as well.

Answer (score 1):

I’d use the word “inhabit” as for me it communicates thats its inside your bag (or takes up space) yet not necessarily the only thing there. i was also thinking “haunts” as a long second.

Comment: Both would work in humour. My handbag is inhabited by many unexpected things and may well even be haunted. But both verbs suggest that the thing doing them is... well, my initial word choice of "animate" won't do for a ghost, but at any rate conscious. I had independently thought of "possessed" as in demonic possession as a single verb taking a direct object and meaning "to be within". However a demonically possessed handbag is a little more exciting than the concept I had in mind with the apples.